# FFMPEG, Extract first frame and hold for 5 seconds

Tags: filter, ffmpeg, concatenation

I'm trying to overlay a 15 second video transition on the beginning of an image sequence (png sequence with an alpha to reveal the image below), which I can do fine with the overlay filter. But I want to hold the first frame of the image sequence for 5 seconds before playing the animation. I've tried trim/select but I can't seem to get it be a duration of 5 seconds, I also can't seem to concat it back with the other video to do the transition. So my questions are:

1. How do I get the first frame and hold it for 5 seconds, the method below works but doesn't seem like the cleanest option?

> -framerate 30 -t 60.0 -i input1.%04d.jpg -framerate 30 -t 15.0 -i transition1_%03d.png -filter_complex "color=c=red:d=5:s=480x270:r=30[bg]; [bg][1:v]overlay[transhold]; [0:v][transhold]overlay=repeatlast=0[out]"

2. How can I concat that with the original before I overlay it on the main video, I can do it with two overlays with the start of the actual transition offset by the length of the hold using the command below, but it seems a bit clunky.

> -framerate 30 -t 60.0 -i input1.%04d.jpg -framerate 30 -t 15.0 -i transition1_%03d.png -filter_complex "color=c=red:d=5:s=480x270:r=30[bg]; [1:v]split[trans][transhold]; [trans]setpts=PTS+5/TB[trans];[transhold]select=eq(n\0)[transhold];[bg][transhold]overlay[transhold]; [0:v][transhold]overlay=repeatlast=0[tmp1]; [tmp1][trans]overlay[out]"

This is all part of a larger command where I'm compiling four HD images into a 4k feed each with it's own transition so the cleaner I can be the better really.  I'd also like to be able to vary the duration of the hold for the different HD inputs.  If I need to I could bring in the first image as a different input but I would still need to concat them. I thought there must be a way to do this with filters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered in another post:
https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/23551/ffmpeg-extract-first-frame-and-hold-for-5-seconds

```
-framerate 30 -t 60.0 -i input1.%04d.jpg 
-framerate 30 -t 15.0 -i transition1_%03d.png 
    -filter_complex 
        "[1]loop=149:1:0[trans];
         [0][trans]overlay=eof_action=pass" out.mp4
```

The first frames of the second input is repeated 149 times, so that there are 150 instances (30 fps x 5s). The 0 at the end of loop is the starting index of the frame(s) to loop. The middle 1 is the number of frames to loop starting at the index in the 3rd argument.